# Debugging a long running Webservice Call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, debugging

I'm using C# to connect to a Webservice to grab data. However, I'm currently having problems getting the code to run on a remote server; when I say problems, I mean its running, but the connection speed between client and server is ridiculously slow (through no fault of mine - the client is providing a slow resultset via a webservice, and they have all timeouts turned off their side in order to do so.)

```
 if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.SFFService))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                result.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                result.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                result.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                return result;
            }
```

So. Not a great start. Open Close and Send all set to maximum.

Anyway, I've matched their long timeouts my side, and a few of the smaller webservice requests finish and succeed ok on the server. The biggest, slowest one however just hangs indefinitely, probably because I've told it to never timeout.

However, I'm pretty sure there's some other problem happening, as I left it overnight and it just sat there. Locally, on my development machine, although slow, it works.

My question is, has anyone any idea on additional things to check about the environment that could potentially be in play here? I thought perhaps firewall, but given that the small requests succeed (and connect) it is very difficult to debug the slow requests as I've no idea how long to wait until accepting that the program isn't going to do anything.

FWIW I've tried connecting via a browser, and again, the browser just sits there waiting for the request to finish which it never does (most likely due to the timeout being turned off on the server). If there was any way to see even how much of the request was left to finish (like a percentage download) that may help give me some guidance as to if the code is doing anything other than waiting.

Comment: Are both your client app and browser behind a proxy? If so, proxy could be timing out also - try bypassing the proxy?

Comment: @Allumearz locally no. remotely- how would i check?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get a progress of the remote call even when you are attached to the remote process. Try using a local Visual Studio on the server machine (preferably on a non-production VM) and attach to the local process rather than using the Remote Debugger.

I am not sure exactly what the question is but the first step I'd take while debugging a slow application would be to test a local connection (local client and local server) to eliminate the network from the equation. If that works well, try hosting the server on a different place (public cloud maybe?) and try again there, if it works well then there's definitely something en-route or on that server.

If you're interested in tracking how long web service calls take you could track it by placing the start time into the HttpContext.Current.Items or OperationContext.Current.Items on BeginRequest/EndRequest in Global.asax or in a MessageInspector if you use WCF (you can send the datetime between the two methods by returning it into the Before method and read it from the corelationState parameter in the After method).